# SYSDATE not working while time comparison in java

Tags: spring, oracle, spring-jdbc

i am using spring jdbc template. i am compairing time in query which is not working as sysdate  consider timezone.

```
select * from Emp where TSLASTMODIFIED < SYSDATE - (  45/(24*60));
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get UTC value for SYSDATE on Oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157873/how-to-get-utc-value-for-sysdate-on-oracle)

Comment: am calling this from java, not running directly on sql or toad

Comment: You don't have any Java code here... how are we meant to know that this is related to Java? If the SQL you're running is not returning the correct the result then the fact that you're calling the SQL in Java doesn't matter.

Comment: ok, i am calling the above mention sql query from java code. when i run the same query in toad its give me correct result but when i call it from java code it give me wrong result . it seems something related to timezine issue with sysdate. Can you help now

Comment: What's the data type of the TSLASTMODIFIED column?

Answer (score 0):

If you apply the information in the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157873/how-to-get-utc-value-for-sysdate-on-oracle) you get:

```
select * from Emp where TSLASTMODIFIED < CAST(sys_extract_utc(SYSTIMESTAMP) AS DATE) - (  45/(24*60));
```

If TSLASTMODIFIED uses some other timezone than UTC you need to modify the SQL accordingly.