# Columns with datatype "TimeStamp(6) With local Time Zone" showing 1hr extra compare to actual DB value

Tags: java, oracle

I am using weblogic server and oracle as a backend for my j2ee application.

we have multiple columns with data type as `TIMESTAMP(6) WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE` along with other column data type as `TIMESTAMP(6)`. issue is though values are same for each column 1hr extra displayed in UI. In UI we simply doing `SimpleDateFormat` using java.

DB values are for all three column are 
`23-SEP-15 03.37.52.958000000 PM`

But IN UI it is displayed as for `TIMESTAMP(6) WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE` fields
`23-SEP-15 04.37.52.958000000 PM`

Server it is showing correct time zone.any Idea what it went wrong.

Java code displaying dateFiled

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
.........................
.............................
....some code goes here..........
..getting the values from DB and converting it to value Objects... 

String dateValue = sdf.format(valueBO.getDateValue()).toString();
.....
 Just given lines of code how i am converting the DB value
...........
```

On page it displays `23-Sep-15 03.37.52.938 PM`

+update
any issue with `DBTIMEZONE`.

Comment: What is the timezone of the current session? What is the result of `SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP, 'TZR') FROM dual`

Comment: SQL> SELECT SYSTIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, LOCALTIMESTAMP FROM dual;

SYSTIMESTAMP
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
LOCALTIMESTAMP
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
23-SEP-15 04.13.08.736000 PM +05:30
23-SEP-15 04.13.08.736000 PM +05:30
23-SEP-15 04.13.08.736000 PM  any issues with DBTIMEZONE?

Comment: Please share the Java code you use for displaying the time stamp.

Comment: What time zone do the `with local time zone` columns show, and what is the DBTIMEZONE? Suspect the values are in a different zone (1 hour out) and the Java query is converting them. Please show the queries and related Java code. (Edit the question to show more info, including the query you put as a comment earlier; it's not easy to read code in comments)

Comment: it is working perfect in my local server but not working at client test environment at node level.

Comment: Please post everything that's relevant, i.e. what does `valueBO.getDateValue()` refer to?

Comment: Regarding `DBTIMEZONE` have a look at this post: [How to handle Day Light Saving in Oracle database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29271224/how-to-handle-day-light-saving-in-oracle-database/29272926#29272926)

Comment: @user1268890, I did not asked for `SYSTIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, LOCALTIMESTAMP`, I asked for `TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP, 'TZR')` and `SESSIONTIMEZONE`! That is different.

Comment: TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP,'TZR')
--------------------------------
+05:30