# oracle 12c forms taking timezone -5:30

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, weblogic12c, oracleforms

I have oracle 12c WebLogic and Oracle 12c Database installed on my windows server. 
On my database dbtimezone is giving me +00:00 which I want but on my forms builder when I'm running forms it taking -5:50 time.

Like if I enter 16:30 time on DateTime field then on the forms field it auto takes 10:00 automatically which means it's converting to -5:30.

As earlier, my timezone of the database was also -5:30 but then I changed my time zone to +00:00 So on database timezone is showing correct but oracle forms timezone is still not correct.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What are your server's [timezone settings](http://www.novibeograd.co.rs/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/ads-image011-1024x576.jpg) ?

Comment: my server timezone settings are
(UTC +5:30) India timezone.

Comment: Ok,thank you for checking this. And now please run within your WebLogic server this simple program, and retrieve it's output from the log: `TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
System.out.println( String.format("Time zone=%s, raw offset = %s, daylight savings = %s ", tz.getDisplayName(), tz.getRawOffset(), tz.useDaylightTime() ));` This will tell you what timezone settings are configured on the server (jdbc driver borrows these settings from server's JVM).

Comment: `DBTIMEZONE` not not relevant for any display value, it is just the internal timezone of `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE` data types, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29271224/how-to-handle-day-light-saving-in-oracle-database/29272926#29272926

Comment: The problem occurring at the time when Oracle form runs as it converts the DateTime field to time zone -5:30 like if I type 16:00 then as soon as I go to next field it changes to 10:30 time.

This problem is in oracle forms 12c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Adding NLS_DATE_FORMAT=DD-MM-YYYY in the registry for both Oracle DB and Oracle form services and altering the dbtimezone worked for me.

For altering the dbtimezone I referred [this link](https://www.carajandb.com/en/blog/2016/be-careful-when-setting-the-dbtimezone/).

Answer (score 3):

You need to add in your forms environment file the following line:

> FORMS_DATETIME_LOCAL_TZ=GMT