# Oracle DBTIMEZONE

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

If I execute `select systimestamp from dual;` I've got timestamp like this `10.04.19 14.45.35 +03:00` and it's correct.

But when I execute `select dbtimezone, sessiontimezone from dual;` there return me `-07:00 Europe/Moscow`

Why it's happend? How to take timezone that I've got via `systimestamp`

*Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production*

Comment: Check this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29271224/how-to-handle-day-light-saving-in-oracle-database/29272926#29272926

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit thanks - it's helped a lot