# how to change the database time zone to IST in oci?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I need a bit of help in changing the time zone in the Oracle cloud infrastructure database. by default it is in UTC I want to change to +5:30 ist

Comment: What do you mean by "the time zone"? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29271224/how-to-handle-day-light-saving-in-oracle-database/29272926#29272926

Comment: a standard time is used for common to all as GMT, according to your region the Gmt + the differential time is set.

Comment: Did you read the linked answer? Again, which one of the three different time zones you like to change?

Comment: current_date the first 1 @WernfriedDomscheit

Comment: Ok, this you have to set in your session, not at database level. The answer is given.

Answer (score 0):

Whether you use the Console or the API, the time zone options you can select from are represented in the named region format, for example, America/Los_Angeles. The Console allows you to select UTC, the time zone detected in your browser (if your browser supports time zone detection), or an alternate time zone.

To specify an alternate time zone (the Select another time zone option), you first select a value in the Region or country field to narrow the list of time zones to select from in the Time zone field. In the America/Los_Angeles example, America is the time region and Los_Angeles is the time zone. The options you see in these two fields roughly correlate with the time zones supported in both the Java.util.TimeZone class and on the Linux operating system. If you do not see the time zone you are looking for, try selecting "Miscellaneous" in the Region and country field.

**see here**:https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Database/References/timezones.htm