# How to get summer time or winter time

Tags: sql, oracle

is there a way to get from the Oracle database by SQL if the date time is in summer time or in winter time?
I hope you have understood the question.

I work in Italy and as in most of European Countries, during the summer time there is the practice of advancing clocks during warmer months and so I'd like to know if in Oracle it's possible to get this kind of information.
Oracle version 10g

Thanks in advance

Mark

Comment: Which 'date time' - the current time now, or a value from a column - in which case, what data type is it? [There is a section in the documentation about time zones](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/nlspg/datetime-data-types-and-time-zone-support.html#GUID-7A1BA319-767A-43CC-A579-4DAC7063B243); some data types include TZ, otherwise you'll have to infer it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29271224/how-to-handle-day-light-saving-in-oracle-database

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can find something like.

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE... <YOUR_FORMAT_DESIRED>
```

If you alter the session you can freeze this condition into the environment variables of Oracle.

I wish yo help you