# Convert date oracle's timestamp to ISO-8601 date datatype

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c, datetime-format, iso8601

I am looking for a query in Oracle 12c to convert a `18-12-2003 13:15:00` to `2003-12-18T13:15:00+01:00` in European time zone as datetime datatype.

Is that possible or am I missing something?

Comment: ISO 8601 is not a datatype, but a date display format. `date` datatype has no any format (some exact day is the day for everyone and it doesn't depend on any culture). To be displayed in some format a date had to be converted to the string (`char`  or `varchar2`). What do you want to do with this string?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to convert the string (I assume your input data is a string, rather than proper `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` value), then you can attach the time zone.

There are several time zones in Europe, you must be more specific.

```
FROM_TZ(TO_TIMESTAMP('18-12-2003 13:15:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'Europe/...')
```

Once you did that, you can output the result in arbitrary format:

```
TO_CHAR(
   FROM_TZ(TO_TIMESTAMP('18-12-2003 13:15:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'Europe/...'),
   'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSTZH:TZM'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert all dates in the column to that format for the time zone CET and you are sure that the offset *always* is 1, then you could do this:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(FROM_TZ(TIMESTAMP '2000-03-28 08:00:00', '1:00'),'YYYY"-"MM"-"DD"T"HH24":"MI":"SSTZR') 
   FROM DUAL;
```

However, the question is what to do with daylight savings time. Is the offset going to change when DST goes into effect ? There are a lot of considerations there - this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29271224/how-to-handle-day-light-saving-in-oracle-database) (credits to @Wernfried Domscheit) has a nice overview.

For example if you data is in UTC time zone and you want to display it in CET, then you could convert it like this:

Note there is 2 hours offset in summer and 1 in winter.

```
WITH dates (season,dt) AS
(
  SELECT 'summer', TO_DATE('01-AUG-2021','DD-MON-YYYY') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'winter', TO_DATE('01-JAN-2021','DD-MON-YYYY') FROM DUAL
)
SELECT dt,
       season,
       TO_CHAR(
         FROM_TZ( CAST( dt AS TIMESTAMP ), 'UTC' )
           AT TIME ZONE 'CET',
         'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS TZH:TZM TZR'
       ) AS cet_timezone
FROM   dates;

01-AUG-2021 summer  2021-08-01 02:00:00 +02:00 CET
01-JAN-2021 winter  2021-01-01 01:00:00 +01:00 CET
```