# Timestamp set at database server and database is UTC, but timestamp is getting loaded as MST in Oracle

Tags: linux, oracle, unix, utc

Application server is showing date as UTC, database server also showing as UTC. When we are inserting systimestamp in a timestamp column from database server then it is showing as UTC format but if we insert from application server then data is getting loaded in MST timezone.

Need some help to figure out what is the issue.

Comment: What is the data type of these columns? What is "MST" timezone? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29271224/how-to-handle-day-light-saving-in-oracle-database/29272926#29272926

Comment: Datatype is TIMESTAMP. MST is UTC-7 hours. Database server is also in UTC timezone but do we need to change anything in application server from where the insert is being called?

Comment: You provided the current situation, please let us also know what you like to get instead of this. All times in UTC or all times as local time (i.e. MST/MDT)?

Comment: Everything we want in UTC.

Answer (score 0):

How do you insert date from application server? Most likely as `LOCALTIMESTAMP` or `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

You have several possibilities:

- Change timezone of your application server to `UTC`
- Use `SYSTIMESTAMP` instead of `LOCALTIMESTAMP` or `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`
- Insert `LOCALTIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'` or `SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(LOCALTIMESTAMP)`

Comment: We are inserting SYSTIMESTAMP from the application server. And when I am running date command in my application server it is showing me date in UTC only. 
"Fri Mar  4 10:52:20 UTC 2022" . What exactly needs to be changed when you are saying "Change timezone of your application server to UTC".

Comment: `SYSTIMESTAMP` insert current time at **database** server operating system time zone, so it should not make any difference from which host you insert `SYSTIMESTAMP`.