# Convert epoch time to timestamp in oracle database with system timezone

Tags: sql, oracle

Can someone please suggest me how to convert epoch time to timestamp in oracle including the database timezone. I am currently using below code:

```
cast ( TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('1970-01-01 00:00:00.0 UTC', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF TZR') + NUMTODSINTERVAL(value/1000, 'SECOND') as timestamp with local time zone)
```

But it appears this is converting to the sessiontimezone. I need it to be converted to dbtimezone

(In my case select dbtimezone gives PST time and select sessiontimezone gives Asia/Calcutta time.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data type `timestamp with local time zone` **always** shows date/time at `SESSIONTIMEZONE`

Try

```
(TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('1970-01-01 00:00:00.0 UTC', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF TZR') + NUMTODSINTERVAL(value/1000, 'SECOND')) AT TIME ZONE DBTIMEZONE
```

Or with literals:

```
(Timestamp '1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC' + value/1000 * INTERVAL '1' SECOND) AT TIME ZONE DBTIMEZONE
```

Comment: hi @Wernfried Tried using AT TIME ZONE DBTIMEZONE earlier but getting syntax error at DBTIMEZONE "ORA-00905: missing keyword"

Comment: also, is it possible to convert to SYSDATE or SYSTIMESTAMP instead of DBTIMEZONE?

Comment: You must put it in brackets `(TIMESTAMP ... + NUMTODSINTERVAL ...) AT TIME ZONE DBTIMEZONE`

Comment: Yes, would be `... AT TIME ZONE TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP, 'tzr')`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29271224/how-to-handle-day-light-saving-in-oracle-database/29272926#29272926

Comment: thanks a lot, the SYSTIMESTAMP worked