# Different time sysdate and current_date when connect to database since application server

Tags: oracle, unix

I have a problem with the time that Oracle gives me when working with applications.

I currently connect from an application server (apx1) to a server containing Oracle 19c (bdx1) for database operations.

Both the application server and the database server are in the Canary Islands, so it must show/work local time there (GMT +1 in summer, GMT in winter).

If I launch the date command on the servers, the time appears correct.

```bash
[oracle@apx1 oracle]$ date
vie jul  1 14:25:49 BST 2022
```

```bash
[oracle@bdx1 ~]$ date
vie jul  1 14:25:46 BST 2022
```

However, after making the connection from apx1 to bdx1, I get this time offset:

```sql
SQL> select systimestamp, current_timestamp, localtimestamp from dual;
SYSTIMESTAMP
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
LOCALTIMESTAMP
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
01/07/22 15:27:39,762772 +02:00
01/07/22 14:27:39,762775 +01:00
01/07/22 14:27:39,762775
```

The SESSIONTIMEZONE parameter returns the correct value, +1:

```sql
SQL> SELECT SESSIONTIMEZONE FROM DUAL;

SESSIONTIMEZONE
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
+01:00
```

However, if I run this query (from the application server to the database):

```sql
sac@apx1> sqlplus user/pass@bdx1
SQL> select to_char(sysdate, 'dd mm yyyy hh24:mi:ss') "SYSDATE", to_char(current_date, 'dd mm yyyy hh24:mi:ss') "CURRENT_DATE" from dual;

SYSDATE             CURRENT_DATE
------------------- -------------------
01 07 2022 16:26:23 01 07 2022 15:26:23
```

SYSDATE result is incorrect with respect to the time that should appear.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29271224/how-to-handle-day-light-saving-in-oracle-database/29272926#29272926

Comment: `SESSIONTIMEZONE = +01:00` might be wrong. `+01:00` means 1 hour ahead UTC - **always**, no matter if you are in Winter or Summer. Still not clear what you consider as "correct". Did you read the linked answer? `sysdate` and `systimestamp` are given in the time zone of the database server operating system. Change it, if you are not happy with it. Or use a function which is returned in your session time zone.

Comment: Yes, the problem is that if I run the query locally in the database server (bdx1) the time comes out correctly (Canary Islands time). But if I connect remotely from the application server (apx1), the time I get is the time in Spain (where there is a time difference of one hour more).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was posted on DBA stackexchange: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/314026/175060.

You have to set the parameter at cluster level:

```bash
srvctl setenv database -db DBNAME -env "TZ=Atlantic/Canary".
```

And then restart the DB hosts, since a CRS restart is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "configure to correct this offset"?

- `LOCALTIMESTAMP` returns the current date and time in the **session time zone** in a value of datatype `TIMESTAMP`.
- `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` returns the current date and time in the **session time zone** in a value of datatype `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`.
- `SYSTIMESTAMP` returns the current date and time in the **time zone of database server's operating system** in a value of datatype `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`.

Set the `SESSIONTIMEZONE` and/or database server time zone properly.

Comment: More information in the question