# How to show date in local time zone in Oracle?

Tags: oracle

I have a database used by users in different timezones.

The database server is let's say in **+01:00 timezone**.

Here is my need:

- When User A in **TZ +01:00** inserts a date/time, for example **August 25, 2022 16h30m** it should be stored in the database as **August 25, 2022 16h30m**
- When User B in **TZ 00:00** inserts **August 25, 2022 16h30m**, it should be stored in the database as **August 25, 2022 17h30m**. And whenever he is connected, he should always see **August 25, 2022 16h30m**

  ```
  User Region       value inserted      What he sees        what is stored in DB
  ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  +01:00            Aug 25, 22 16h30m   Aug 25, 22 16h30m   Aug 25, 22 16h30m
  +00:00            Aug 25, 22 16h30m   Aug 25, 22 16h30m   Aug 25, 22 17h30m
  ```

I tried all different Date formats like this:

```
alter table SomeTable add(Col_A_Date DATE);
alter table SomeTable add(Col_B_TimeStamp TIMESTAMP);
alter table SomeTable add(Col_C_TimeStampWithTimeZone TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE);
alter table SomeTable add(Col_D_TimeStampWithLocalTimeZone TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE);

-- Assuming it's User A : set time zone to GMT + 1
alter session set time_zone='+1:00';

-- Inserting data in the table as User A
insert into SomeTable (Col_A_Date, Col_B_TimeStamp, Col_C_TimeStampWithTimeZone, Col_D_TimeStampWithLocalTimeZone) values (sysdate, sysdate, sysdate, sysdate);

-- Query data
select * from SomeTable;
```

Result :

[image]

```
-- Now assuming it's User B who is in another region : Changing session to GMT
alter session set time_zone='+0:00';

-- Query data. Here I expect user B to see different values
select * from SomeTable;
```

Result :

[image]

As seen in the results, nothing changes in the display of values for all the timestamp columns.

Which datatype should I use to store my dates, and how to show them automatically based on the region the user is connected from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your requirements I would suggest data type `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE`

For this data type the data is stored in `DBTIMEZONE` - which can set to `+01:00`, if you prefer. The data is **always** shown in current user session time zone, i.e. at `SESSIONTIMEZONE`

Note, changing `DBTIMEZONE` requires a database restart. You cannot modify `DBTIMEZONE` if you have already a table with a `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE` column which contains any data.

Your problem is `SYSDATE`. `SYSDATE` returns a `DATE` value **in the time zone of database server's operating system**. The `DATE` value itself does not contain any time zone information, Oracle defaults it to `SESSIONTIMEZONE`.

Try

```
insert into SomeTable (
   Col_A_Date, 
   Col_B_TimeStamp, 
   Col_C_TimeStampWithTimeZone, 
   Col_D_TimeStampWithLocalTimeZone) 
values (
  CURRENT_DATE, 
  LOCALTIMESTAMP, 
  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

Then the output should be what you expect.

See also [How to handle Day Light Saving in Oracle database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29271224/how-to-handle-day-light-saving-in-oracle-database/29272926#29272926)