# Setting Oracle Session Time Zone Does Not Work

Tags: oracle

I have a multi-tenant Oracle 23c database, and when I select SYSDATE from dual, I get UTC zone.  I altered the database to set the TIME_ZONE = 'US/Eastern'.  I shutdown the database and restarted it.  When I select the SYSDATE, it still has the time as UTC.  How can I change the database time zone to Eastern?

Comment: You can change the time zone, but SYSDATE will not use it: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/nlspg/datetime-data-types-and-time-zone-support.html#NLSPG263

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29271224/how-to-handle-day-light-saving-in-oracle-database/29272926#29272926 - you need to change the time zone of the database server operating system.