# oracle job "next run date"

Tags: oracle, job-scheduling

My oracle database time zone is +03:30 (TEHRAN)

```
select current_timestamp from dual

22-JAN-24 11.06.09.128998 AM +03:30


 dbms_scheduler.create_job (
              job_name          => v_job_name ,
              job_type          => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
              job_class         => 'DEFAULT_JOB_CLASS',
              job_action        => v_stmt,
              start_date        => SYSDATE,
              enabled           => TRUE,
              auto_drop         => TRUE
              );
```

but when we set a job to be runned immediately in my current sysdate ,My job run after 3.5 hours !

but we expect that my job run immediatly;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"My oracle database time zone is +03:30 (TEHRAN)" - What does it mean?

See [How to handle Day Light Saving in Oracle database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29271224/how-to-handle-day-light-saving-in-oracle-database/29272926#29272926)

`current_timestamp` returns the current time in your `SESSIONTIMEZONE`, however `SYSDATE` returns the current time in the time zone of database server's operating system.

Parameter `start_date` has data type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`, your input value is converted implicitly as

```
FROM_TZ(CAST(SYSDATE AS TIMESTAMP), SESSIONTIMEZONE)
```

However, in principle you would require

```
FROM_TZ(CAST(SYSDATE AS TIMESTAMP), TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP, 'tzr'))
```

Try

```
dbms_scheduler.create_job (
          job_name          => v_job_name ,
          job_type          => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
          job_class         => 'DEFAULT_JOB_CLASS',
          job_action        => v_stmt,
          start_date        => CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
          enabled           => TRUE,
          auto_drop         => TRUE
          );
```

or

```
dbms_scheduler.create_job (
          job_name          => v_job_name ,
          job_type          => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
          job_class         => 'DEFAULT_JOB_CLASS',
          job_action        => v_stmt,
          start_date        => SYSTIMESTAMP,
          enabled           => TRUE,
          auto_drop         => TRUE
          );
```

Either of them should work.

Comment: Thank you , as you said `SYSTIMESTAMP` return the server time with time zone . and `SELECT SYSTIMESTAMP from dual` returns `23-JAN-24 02.10.33.707840 PM +03:30`  that shows that "My oracle database time zone is +03:30 (Iran/TEHRAN)" . But my job run after 3.5 hours after this time. did I missed some thing in 'enviroment dataBase attribute' ?

Comment: I use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and my problem did be  solved, But I did not understand the issue

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT FROM_TZ(CAST(TO_DATE('22-JAN-24 11.06.09.128998', 

      'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS:FFF') AS TIMESTAMP), 'Iran/Tehran') 
   AT TIME ZONE 'Iran/Tehran' "Tehran Time" 
   FROM DUAL;

Tehran Time
```

Comment: thank you, but i think that we should change or review  some thing in 'enviroment dataBase attribute'

Comment: String `'22-JAN-24 11.06.09.128998'` does not reflect format `'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS:FFF'`. Apart from that `Iran/Tehran` is a invalid time zone, check with `select * from V$TIMEZONE_NAMES`

Comment: It's a bit pointless to make "apply time zone `Iran/Tehran` to timestamp and then convert it to time zone `Iran/Tehran`"